# How to access CSRF token from response header?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jwt, csrf, csrf-token

I want to access CSRF token of a HTTP request's response header

**Chrome Dev Tools Network Tab Image**
[image]

**Chrome Dev Tools Console Image**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access CSRF token from the DOM's metadata.

`const csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;`